# Laravel 7 multiselect in a one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the selected saved values of my multi select, without success.

I have the following code:

```
public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tags_dashboard', 'dashboard_id', 'tag_id');
    }
```

I want the selected values to be selected. This does not seem to work:

```
<select id="tags" name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple>
        @foreach($tags as $tag)
          <option value="{{$tag->id}}" @foreach($tags as $dashboard->tag) {{ in_array($tag->id, $dashboard->tag) ? "selected" : null }} @endforeach>{{$tag->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

It gives the error `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

Comment: Use ``` in_array($tag->id, $dashboard->tag()->pluck("tags.id")->toArray()) ```

Comment: Thank you @Kristian! That did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the logic correct there, it's just syntax/notation problem

In place of:

`in_array($tag->id, $dashboard->tag)`

Use:

`in_array($tag->id, $dashboard->tag()->pluck("tags.id")->toArray())`

Explanation:

- `$tag->id` returns the ID (int from database)
- since you have defined the relationship between dashboard and tags (with belongsToMany function), you just need to get an array that contains all the tag IDs of the variable `$dashboard`
- `$dashboard->tag()` returns the relationship between $dashboard and its tags
- `$dashboard->tag()->pluck("tags.id")` returns a laravel collection object that holds all tag IDs of $dashboard's tags
- `$dashboard->tag()->pluck("tags.id")->toArray()`: the last toArray function convert a laravel collection object to php native array